# Database not configured laravel during migration

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

This might be repeated question. But I had no luck with previous answers

I just `git clone` a laravel project. Now I tried to do `php artisan migrate`. It returns the below error.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]   
Database [] not configured.
```

and

```
migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]
```

my `app/config/database.php` is like this:

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'upgrade',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

I do create the `upgrade` database in `mysql`.

could anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please run `php artisan env` to see what the enviroment is?

Comment: Which operation system do you use?

Comment: do you have a database-user 'root' with a password of 'root'?

Comment: Check if the variables aren't being overwritten somewhere - the database[] might mean that that variable is changed to blank somewhere?

Comment: Environment is set in the `.env` file.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Database [mysql] not configured. If I ran php artisan cache:clear or config:cache I would get the same error. I solved it by going into laravel/bootstrap/cache and deleting the config.php file that was there, and then running the above commands again. I believe it was a file permission error that was preventing the cached config.php file from actually being cleared.

Comment: For me the issue was `DB_CONNECTION` set incorrectly for PostgreSQL, it should be `pgsql`

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. I have cloned the L5.1 project from GIT and i performed

```
composer install 
composer update
```

and also configured DB details in .env (by default .env is not present so i took the copy of .env.example and renamed as .env). After that if tried to run

```
 php artisan migrate
```

I got the same exception like as @users4393829 mentioned. I tried follow commands to find and set the database.

```
 php artisan tinker
 >>> Config::get('database.connections.mysql.database');
 >>>null
 >>>Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database','homesteaed');
 >>>Config::get('database.connections.mysql.database');
 >>>homesteaed
```

After doing all this things i found that there is no database.php file so i have placed it in the 'config' folder and ran the migration it works. Please make sure that you have any config files is git ignored in your project.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution which worked is to cache config:
`php artisan config:cache`
like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774946/database-not-configured-laravel-5/47037187#47037187)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove .env file and put new to replace

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turns out the `.env` that shipped with the framework defaulted the `DB_HOST` to `localhost` and had DB_PORT set.

Changed the host to the FQDN of the machine and it worked fine.  I'm guessingif you're connecting to `localhost` it expects a socket and not a port.