# Database [system] not configured

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to setup passport on laravel 5.5 but whenever i run **php artisan migrate**, i get **Database [system] not configured**. I am not sure why i am getting this error. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: check `.env` file.Check all database information is right or wrong.

Comment: can you please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304002/6556397)

Comment: which method you used to install `passport` ? update `composer.json` or `require` command ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple database in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-laravel)

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud I checked .env and the database information looks right.

Comment: @user2486 I used require command. Thanks.

Comment: Try `composer update` and check

Comment: @user2486 Okay let me check. THanks.

Comment: @user2486 It still does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @rahulsm I have checked the link and database.php is in my config directory.

Comment: Can you post your .env in your question?

Comment: also share `database.php` inside `config` folder ?

Comment: Hi Guys, 

I got it to work after changing the database. I had another package which needed a database with the name "system". Thanks all :)