# Database connection [users] not configured

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting `InvalidArgumentException` `Database connection [users] not configured.` http://127.0.0.1:8000/register  error, when submitting register form, using Laravel Auth. My Laravel version is 6.17.1

**.env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**Auth/RegisterController.php file**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:20'],
            'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
            'age' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:100'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users.email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6'],
            'confirm' => ['required', 'string', 'same:password']
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Yerevan");
        $created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'surname'=> $data['surname'],
            'age' => $data['age'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'created_at' => $created
        ]);
    }
}
```

**app/User.php file**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surname', 'age', 'email', 'password', 'code', 'ban', 'ban_reason', 'created_at', 'image', 'role', 'confirmed'
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'code', 'confirmed'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**users table migration file**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 20);
            $table->string('surname', 30);
            $table->integer('age');
            $table->string('image', 255);
            $table->string('email', 255);
            $table->string('password', 255);
            $table->integer('code')->default(0);
            $table->string('ban', 255);
            $table->string('ban_reason', 255);
            $table->string('role', 255)->default("user");
            $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
            $table->dateTime('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**config/database.php file**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

**auth.php file**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

I have tried change .env file, clear cache and config, but no result.

**UPD1:**  dd(config('database'));

```
array:4 [▼
  "default" => "mysql"
  "connections" => array:4 [▼
    "sqlite" => array:5 [▶]
    "mysql" => array:15 [▼
      "driver" => "mysql"
      "url" => null
      "host" => "127.0.0.1"
      "port" => "3306"
      "database" => "geeknews"
      "username" => "root"
      "password" => ""
      "unix_socket" => ""
      "charset" => "utf8mb4"
      "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
      "prefix" => ""
      "prefix_indexes" => true
      "strict" => true
      "engine" => null
      "options" => []
    ]
    "pgsql" => array:12 [▶]
    "sqlsrv" => array:10 [▶]
  ]
  "migrations" => "migrations"
  "redis" => array:4 [▶]
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database not configured laravel during migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548044/database-not-configured-laravel-during-migration)

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur No, table is creating successfull, there is no problem with migration.

Comment: did you try steps in there??

Comment: one of your models (if not the user model) has this line ` protected $connection = 'users';` remove it or set it to mysql. verify also that in the .env `DB_CONNECTION=mysql`

Comment: Please reply the content of config/auth.php

Comment: setup your db config directly in your config/db.php and check

Comment: @user8555937 post is updated, check

Comment: @Narek check my answer. If it doesn't help you, in your controller please append `dd(config('database'));` and reply the results.

Comment: @N69S I only have User model

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had same error and it occurred because of wrong validation role.

i got this error :

```
{
"message": "Database connection [users] not configured.",
"exception": "InvalidArgumentException", ... 
}
```

Check your validation rules again especially on [unique] rules.

My Wrong code :

```
$rules = [
         'username'  => 'required|min:8|unique:users.username,'.$request->input('user-id')
];
```

And right ones :

```
$rules = [
         'username'  => 'required|min:8|unique:users,username,'.$request->input('user-id')
];
```

You have same problem in 'Auth/RegisterController.php':
replace this :

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:20'],
        'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
        'age' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:100'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users.email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6'],
        'confirm' => ['required', 'string', 'same:password']
    ]);
}
```

with this :

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:20'],
        'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
        'age' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:100'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6'],
        'confirm' => ['required', 'string', 'same:password']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: After this error, I closed the project, but the same problem appeared in the next project, because of the validation that you noted, I fixed it a month ago and everything works fine, thanks for the answer. There was no way back to the previous project, so I did not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

First run `php artisan config:cache & php artisan cache:clear` and try again. If the issue persists, you can manually specify the database connection within Users model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    # database connection
    protected $connection = 'mysql';


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surname', 'age', 'email', 'password', 'code', 'ban', 'ban_reason', 'created_at', 'image', 'role', 'confirmed'
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'code', 'confirmed'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

---

Normally this shouldn't be necessary, as your application uses `mysql` as default connection, though I don't know your environment. Problem could be anywhere. Hope this helps.

Comment: dd (config('database')) returns

array:4 [▼
  "default" => "mysql"
  "connections" => array:4 [▶]
  "migrations" => "migrations"
  "redis" => array:4 [▶]
]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on my Laravel 8.x and for solving your problem you have to change the validation rule for email input from `unique:users.email` to `unique:users,email` just like this:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:20'],
        'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
        'age' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:100'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6'],
        'confirm' => ['required', 'string', 'same:password']
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with change

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
```

to

```
DB_CONNECTION=localhost
```

Comment: the wrong answer, localhost  is a host should on `DB_HOST`, not  `DB_CONNECTION`